# to change the column name in postgresql as current_date

Tags: postgresql

I want to change a column name to `current_date`, e.g.:

```sql
select date from table_name as current_date
```

but `current_date` should be today's date

I've tried using double quotes but they didn't work.

Comment: You should not use dynamic column names.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you select a current date in SQL,

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) AS current_date
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: `current_date` is a SQL keyword that returns - surprise - the current date. The result of `DATE(NOW())` is equivalent to the result of `current_date`

Comment: I tought you want the current_date and not the column name, I'm running this query `select "createdAt" as current_date from experiences;` and it's returning the createdAt with that alias, i.m not sure why you have otherwise.

Comment: I don't want anything. But I _think_ nakul arora wants to have a result where the column `date` gets the alias `"2023-02-22"` if run today and `"2023-02-23"` if run tomorrow. But nevertheless your code is equivalent to `select current_date from table_name`